# unable to add a search core result web part inside my enterprise wiki site collection

Tags: development, web-part, publishing-site, query, search-configuration

I have two site collections inside the same web application; siteA & siteB. now inside siteA i want to display the latest items from siteB. i read a lot about cross-site query , and it seems that search core result web part can achieve this, but inside my publishing site (of type enterprise wiki) i can not find the "search core" web part inside the available web parts list. so can anyone adivce ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna display the latest items, i think you mean the Content Search Web Part. For this you need the enterprise license as it is not available to the foundation nor the standard edition.

If you have a Enterprise license, add it by activating the `Search-Driven content` feature.

[SharePoint 2013 feature comparison chart all editions](http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/#SER)

For the Search Results, refiners, advanced search box and the other related web parts, make sure that the feature `Search Server Web Parts and Templates` are activated from the site collection features setting.

[Enable or disable site collection features](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/enable-or-disable-site-collection-features-HA102772720.aspx)

Comment: yes i have an enterprise license , and i have enabled the "Search Server web Parts and template" site feature. but still i can not find the "Content search web part"?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the great reply, Currently I added a new content search web part , inside my team site, and I click on “change query” button. But I am not sure how I can reference the enterprise wiki site's wiki page library and to specify that I need to get the latest 10 wiki pages? Can anyone advice please ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should start a new question for that, as that goes beyond my knowledge.